# Rails trying to join 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my models:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :application_fields
  has_many :application_fields_values
end

class ApplicationField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_many :application_fields_values
end

class ApplicationFieldsValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :application_field
end
```

Here's the query i'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT `application_fields_values`.* , `application_fields`.*, `templates`.*
FROM `application_fields_values` 
  INNER JOIN `application_fields` ON `application_fields`.`id` = `application_fields_values`.`application_field_id`
  inner join `templates` on `templates`.`id` = `application_fields`.`template_id`
```

Here's what i've got:

```
@report = ApplicationFieldsValue.joins(:application_field, :template)
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Association named 'template' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

How can I achieve the query above using active record?

Comment: try to pluralize the name(s)

Comment: What should `@result` evaluate to? Should it be ApplicationFieldsValue instances? Or do you want a Hash with values from all the joined tables?

Comment: I need somes values from each of the tables so to make my query shorter for this question i just used all the tables.*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your goal is with your target query because it is selecting all fields from all tables involved. What do you expect `@result` to contain?

I think this is along the lines of how you want your relations set up.

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :application_fields
  has_many :application_fields_values, :through => :application_fields
end

class ApplicationField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_many :application_fields_values
end

class ApplicationFieldsValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :application_field
  has_one :template, :through => :application_field
end
```